# How to get a constant initialization from a binding in Eclipse AST?

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I have this Java source:

```
package org.test;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class GetDateFormat {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT =
        new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Date : " + DATE_FORMAT.format(new Date()) + " !");
    }

}
```

I parse it using Eclipse AST.
I get a reference to the `DATE_FORMAT.format(new Date())` method call.
I want to know what date format will be used.
I successfully find a reference to the `DATE_FORMAT` declaration but I'd like to go further and get a reference to the `new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")` initialization declaration and then to the constructor's first argument: `"dd/MM/yyyy"`.

How to do that?

Here is the furthest I've got:

```
private static void getDateFormat(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) {
    // methodInvocation => DATE_FORMAT.format(new Date())
    // methodInvocation.getExpression() => DATE_FORMAT
    if (methodInvocation.getExpression() instanceof SimpleName) {
        // nameBinding => private static final java.text.SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT
        IBinding nameBinding = ((SimpleName) methodInvocation.getExpression()).resolveBinding();
        if (nameBinding instanceof IVariableBinding) {
            IVariableBinding variableBinding = (IVariableBinding) nameBinding;
            // TODO And now what?! How to get the initialization?! : new SDF("dd/MM/yyyy")
        }
    }
}
```

When debugging in Eclipse, I see that `nameBinding` is of type `VariableBinding` and has a field named `binding` of type `LocalVariableBinding` whose field `declaration` is of type `LocalDeclaration` with value `SimpleDateFormat DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")`:

[image: Debug tree of]

So Eclipse knows how `DATE_FORMAT` has been initialized. But the field `binding` is private. Without resorting to dark powers (introspection to get the value of private fields), how to get the `new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")` in a clean way?